# Regex is working properly in Regex coach, but when applied to bash, it isn't anymore

Tags: regex, bash

So here's my code:

```
if [[ $line =~ [A-z]{3}\s[A-z]{3}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\sIST\s[0-9]{4} ]]
then
    echo "hello"
fi
```

Here's the text file:

```
<table width="100%" border=1 align="center">^M
<tr><th width="10%">Serial No.</th><th width="20%">File/Folder Name</th><th width="40%">Modified Date.</th><th width="10%">Size</th><th width="20%">Open/Download</th></tr>^M
<h4>Folder : "Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100"</h4><br>
<tr><td width="10%">1</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_031016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_031016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Mon Oct 03 16:41:33 IST 2016</td><t</td></tr><tr><td width="10%">2</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_041016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_041016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Tue Oct 04 16:43:20 IST 2
</td></tr><tr><td width="10%">3</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_051016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_051016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Wed Oct 05 17:39:48 IST 2</td></tr><tr><td width="10%">4</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_061016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_061016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Thu Oct 06 16:40:29 IST 2
</td></tr><tr><td width="10%">5</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_071016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_071016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Fri Oct 07 16:46:10 IST 2
</td></tr>^M
</table>
```

It is working in regex code, but when i run this in bash, it isn't working anymore. Any suggestion is very much appreciated. thanks :)

Comment: Parsing HTML using BASH regex can be very error prone. `[A-z]` is wrong anyway. It should be `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Does your BASH support `\s`? Use `[[:space:]]` instead. Also, `[[:alpha:]]` is a more precise expression to  match just letters.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to debug a regular expression, it is useful to start with smaller pieces of the expression, building it up as you go, to make sure that you have written it correctly.

i.e. Start with `[A-Za-z]{3}` then `[A-Za-z]{3}\s` then `[A-Za-z]{3}\s[A-Za-z]{3}` ... etc.

Debugging in this way, I notice that `[A-z]` should be `[A-Za-z]` as anubhava suggests, and that you are missing an extra `[0-9]{2}` to capture the day of the month.  Since you are trying to match a 4-digit year, there will be only one matching line:

```
#!/bin/bash

#        Wed          Oct        12        12    :  34    :  56      IST  2016
re='([A-Za-z]{3}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\sIST\s[0-9]{4})'

# Iterate over each line
cat input.html | while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $re ]]
    then
        echo "$line"
        echo "==> ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done
```

**Output**

```
<tr><td width="10%">1</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_031016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_031016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Mon Oct 03 16:41:33 IST 2016</td><t</td></tr><tr><td width="10%">2</td><td width="20%"><a href="Download?path=Nifty Free Float Smallcap 100/Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_041016.zip">Nifty_Free_Float_Smallcap_100_041016.zip</a></td><td width="40%">Tue Oct 04 16:43:20 IST 2
==> Mon Oct 03 16:41:33 IST 2016
```